# How to test filename expansion result in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check whether a directory has files or not in bash. 
My code is here.

```
for d in {,/usr/local}/etc/bash_completion.d ~/.bash/completion.d
     do              
         [ -d "$d" ] && [ -n "${d}/*" ] &&                         

         for f in $d/*; do                                                                                                           
             [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f" && . "$f"                        

         done                                                                                                                        
     done
```

The problem is that "~/.bash/completion.d" has no file. 
So, $d/* is regarded as simple string "~/.bash/completion.d/*", not empty string which is result of filename expansion. 
As a result of that code, bash tries to run

```
. "~/.bash/completion.d/*"
```

and of course, it generates error message.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: In a simple word, I want to know how to enforce filename expansion for  invalid filename string

Answer (score 6):

If you set the nullglob bash option, through

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

then globbing will drop patterns that don't match any file.

Comment: kjshim's code seems to work for me, as is, without setting `nullglob` (`shopt nullglob` returns "off") . Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Perhaps the directories you have been trying were not empty?

Answer (score 5):

```
# NOTE: using only bash builtins
# Assuming $d contains directory path

shopt -s nullglob

# Assign matching files to array
files=( "$d"/* )

if [ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'No files found.'
else
    # Whatever
fi
```

Assignment to an array has other benefits, including desirable (correct!) handling of filenames/paths containing white-space, and simple iteration without using a sub-shell, as the following code does:

```
find "$d" -type f |
while read; do
    # Process $REPLY
done
```

Instead, you can use:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    # Process $file
done
```

with the benefit that the loop is run by the main shell, meaning that side-effects (such as variable assignment, say) made within the loop are visible for the remainder of script. Of course, it's also **way** faster, if performance is an issue.

Finally, an array can also be inserted in command line arguments (without splitting arguments containing white-space):

```
$ md5sum fileA "${files[@]}" fileZ
```

You should always attempt to correctly handle files/paths containing white-space, because one day, they will happen!

Comment: Kudos for the nice example of glob expansion for files, the bash manual is very confusing on that part!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` directly in the following way:

```
for f in $(find {,/usr/local}/etc/bash_completion.d ~/.bash/completion.d -maxdepth 1 -type f);
do echo $f; . $f;
done
```

But `find` will print a warning if some of the directory isn't found, you can either put a `2>  /dev/null` or put the `find` call after testing if the directories exist (like in your code).

Answer (score 0):

```
find() {
 for files in "$1"/*;do
    if [ -d "$files" ];then
        numfile=$(ls $files|wc -l)
        if [ "$numfile" -eq 0 ];then
            echo "dir: $files has no files"
            continue
        fi
        recurse "$files"
    elif [ -f "$files" ];then
         echo "file: $files";
        :
    fi
 done
}
find /path
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
# prelim stuff to set up d
files=`/bin/ls $d`
if [ ${#files} -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No files were found"
else
    # do processing
fi
```